# Jquery, ajax, PHP - Live search not returning values in some situations

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, livesearch

I have a live search going for health card numbers. It is linked with a MySQL database and for the most part it works... Kinda. Im running into a problem where certain strings of numbers seem to give it trouble strings such as 12345689999 (my seven key is broken). It seems to appear when there are the same characters used repeatedly after one another. The data type in my database for the HCN's is text. My code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

         <div class="jumbotron">

             <h1 class="display-3">Search Patient Using Health Card Number</h1>
             <hr class="m-y-2">

             <p class="lead">

                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hcnSearch" aria-describedby="hcn" placeholder="Search health card number">

             </p>

        </div>

        <div id="result">

        </div>

    </div>
```

**Jquery / AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#hcnSearch").keyup(function() {

                var txt =$(this).val();

                if (txt != '') {

                    $('#result').html('');

                    $.ajax({
                        url:"fetch2.php",
                        method: "post",
                        data:{search2:txt},
                        dataType:"text",
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    });


                } else {

                    $('#result').html('');
                }

            });
        });
```

**In my fetch2.php File**

```
<?php
session_start();

include("connection.php");

$output = '';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM PATIENT_ID_DEMO WHERE H_CARD_NUMBER LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["search2"])."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      if ($row[5] == 1) {
          $row5 = "Yes";
      } else {
          $row5 = "No";
      }

      if ($row[8] == "M") {
          $row8 = "Male";
      } else {
          $row8 = "Female";
     }

      $output .= '<h4 align="center">Search Result</h4>';  
      $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">  
                    <table class="table table bordered">  
                        <tr>  
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Middle Name</th>
                            <th>DOB</th>
                            <th>NS health card</th>
                            <th>Health card number</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>UID</th>
                        </tr>';  

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[2].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[4].'</td>
                <td>'.$row5.'</td>
                <td>'.$row[7].'</td>
                <td>'.$row8.'</td>
                <td>'.$row[9].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[10].'</td>
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  echo $output;

}

} else {

   echo "No data found...";

}


?>
```

This code allows me to type (search) 12345689 and the query will show some relevant health card numbers however if I am looking for12345689999 and I type the second 9... all of the searches go away.

Comment: Is there value in dB for for1234568999

Comment: Yes there is, that value even shows up then disapears once the second nine is entered @KARTHISRV

Answer (score 0):

change the method into **GET**

```
$.ajax({
         url:"fetch2.php",
         method: "GET",
         data:{search2:txt},
         dataType:"text",
         success:function(data)
         {
           $('#result').html(data);
         }
      });
```